# Modal base оn a[href^=“#id”]

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to reduce call modal window?

```
$('#button-1').on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-1').addClass('j-modal--open');
});

$('#button-2').on('click', function() {
   $('#modal-2').addClass('j-modal--open');
});
```

For example:

```
var modal__id = $('a[href^="#j-form"]').val();

$('a[href^="#j-form"]').on('click', function() {
    $(modal__id).addClass('j-modal--open');
})
```

Where the contents of the href into a variable and is entered by clicking on the link, is id with the same name and includes the class j-modal--open

That is when you click:

```
<a href="#j-form__id">Click</a>
```

Opened window:

```
<div id="j-form__id">Modal content</div>
```

Comment: It should work if you get the `href` attribute of `this`: `$('a[href^="#j-form"]').on('click', function() { $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('j-modal--open'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting a common class on all the `a` elements which trigger the modal. You can then read the `href` in the click handler of all the `a` and open the appropriate modal. Try this:

```
<a href="#j-form__id" class="modal-trigger">Click</a>
<a href="#foo" class="modal-trigger">Click</a>
```

```js
$('.modal-trigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).addClass('j-modal--open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple. All you need to do is read the href value out of your clicked element and get hash part of the link. Here is an a working example from your code.

First we start off by defining our links. We add the modal-link class to each anchor tag so we know that these should trigger a modal.

```
<a href="#form-id" class="modal-link">Open Modal 1</a>
<a href="#another-form-id" class="modal-link">Open Modal 2</a>
```

Now, we run our jQuery selector to add our click event to all the matched elements on the page.

```
$('a.modal-link').on('click', function() {
    var href = this.href;
    var hashIndex = this.href.indexOf('#');

    if (hashIndex == -1) return false; // Could not find the # symbol that separates our ID

    // Get the ID selector from the URL (includes the # symbol)
    var id = href.substring(hashIndex);
    // Find our modal and add the requested class
    $(id).addClass('j-modal--open');

    // Prevent default action of this link
    return false;
});
```